# Replacing Dynamic SQL in stored procedure is causing trouble

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I have this SQL Server stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE MB34Procedure 
    (@PT AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @LN AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @FirstName AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @LastName AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @City AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL,
     @County AS NVARCHAR(255) = NULL)
AS
BEGIN
    SET ANSI_NULLS OFF;
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    SELECT TOP 10
        p.Spec as PT,
        Tax.LN,
        p.First_Name, p.Last_Name,
        loc.City,
        cou.Name  
    FROM
        D_Provider p
    INNER JOIN 
        D_Location Loc on Loc.D_Provider_ID = p.Id
    INNER JOIN 
        D_Tax Tax on Tax.D_Provider_Id = Loc.D_Provider_ID
    INNER JOIN 
        L_County Cou on cou.Code = loc.County_Id 
    WHERE   
        p.Spec like '%' + @PT + '%' OR @PT IS NULL
        AND Tax.LN LIKE '%' + @LN + '%'  OR @LN IS NULL
        AND p.FirstName LIKE '%' + @FirstName + '%' OR @FirstNameIS NULL
        AND p.LastName LIKE '%' + @LastName + '%' OR @LastName IS NULL
        AND loc.City LIKE '%' + @City + '%' OR @City IS NULL
        AND cou.Name LIKE '%' + @County + '%' OR @County IS NULL
    ORDER BY 
        p.Spec
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);

    SET NOCOUNT OFF;
END;
```

This is supposed to ignore null parameters, correct?

But if I exec like this:

```
EXEC MB34Procedure 'Dentist', null, null, null, null, null, 'Washington'
```

it returns records from other counties (the last parameter). It is supposed to return only dentists from Washington county.

Not sure what is wrong. The procedure originally used dynamic SQL and I think that is just wrong.

Comment: It is a **terrible** idea to set ansi_nulls off. Nor does it do anything useful here. This setting does not affect the concatenation operator - only the comparison (=, <>) operators.

Comment: Understood. I didn't write the original.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis. `AND` has higher precedence than `OR`. Correct where part would be:

```
WHERE   
    (p.Spec like '%' + @PT + '%' OR @PT IS NULL)
    and (Tax.LN like '%' + @LN + '%'  OR @LN IS NULL)
    and  (p.FirstName like '%' + @FirstName + '%' OR @FirstNameIS NULL)
    and  (p.LastName like '%' + @LastName + '%' OR @LastName IS NULL)
    and  (loc.City like '%' + @City + '%' OR @City IS NULL)
    and  (cou.Name like '%' + @County + '%' OR @County IS NULL)
```